# Swing delay between calls

Tags: java, swing, timer, delay

I'm trying to make a program that load 4 images, put it in 4 labels and change the icons of each label in the frame regarding the random number in the list, like if it was blinking the images. It need to blink each image in the order that is sorted in comecaJogo() but when I press the btnComecar in the actionPerformed all imagens seems to change at the same time:

Here is my logic class:

```
public class Logica {

    List<Integer> seqAlea = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> seqInsere = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int placar = 0;
    boolean cabouGame = false;
    Random geraNumero = new Random();
    int numero;
    Timer timer = new Timer(1500,null);

    public void comecaJogo() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            numero = geraNumero.nextInt(4) + 1;
            seqAlea.add(numero);
        }
    }

    public void piscaImagen(ImageIcon img1, ImageIcon img1b, JLabel lbl) {
        timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            int count = 0;
            @Override               
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                if(lbl.getIcon() != img1){
                    lbl.setIcon(img1);
                } else {
                    lbl.setIcon(img1b);
                }
                count++;
                if(count == 2){
                    ((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();
                }
            }
        });
        timer.setInitialDelay(1250);
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

In the frame:

```
public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JLabel lblImg1 = new JLabel();
JButton btnImg1 = new JButton("Economize Energia");
final URL resource1 = getClass().getResource("/br/unip/IMGs/img1.jpg");
final URL resource1b = getClass().getResource("/br/unip/IMGs/img1_b.png");
ImageIcon img1 = new ImageIcon(resource1);
ImageIcon img1b = new ImageIcon(resource1b);

JButton btnImg2 = new JButton("Preserve o Meio Ambiente");
JLabel lblImg2 = new JLabel("");
final URL resource2 = getClass().getResource("/br/unip/IMGs/img2.jpg");
final URL resource2b = getClass().getResource("/br/unip/IMGs/img2_b.jpg");
ImageIcon img2 = new ImageIcon(resource2);
ImageIcon img2b = new ImageIcon(resource2b);

JButton btnImg3 = new JButton("N\u00E3o \u00E0 polui\u00E7\u00E3o!");
JLabel lblImg3 = new JLabel("");
final URL resource3 = getClass().getResource("/br/unip/IMGs/img3.jpg");
final URL resource3b = getClass().getResource("/br/unip/IMGs/img3_b.jpg");
ImageIcon img3 = new ImageIcon(resource3);
ImageIcon img3b = new ImageIcon(resource3b);

JButton btnImg4 = new JButton("Recicle!");
JLabel lblImg4 = new JLabel("");
final URL resource4 = getClass().getResource("/br/unip/IMGs/img4.jpg");
final URL resource4b = getClass().getResource("/br/unip/IMGs/img4_b.jpg");
ImageIcon img4 = new ImageIcon(resource4);
ImageIcon img4b = new ImageIcon(resource4b);

Logica jogo = new Logica();

JButton btnComecar = new JButton("Come\u00E7ar");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main window = new Main();
    window.setVisible(true);

}

public Main() {

    lblImg1.setIcon(img1b);
    lblImg1.setBounds(78, 48, 250, 200);
    add(lblImg1);

    btnImg1.setBounds(153, 259, 89, 23);
    btnImg1.addActionListener(this);
    add(btnImg1);

    setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
    setLayout(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    btnImg2.setBounds(456, 272, 186, 23);
    btnImg2.addActionListener(this);
    lblImg2.setIcon(img2b);
    lblImg2.setBounds(421, 61, 250, 200);
    add(btnImg2);
    add(lblImg2);

    btnImg3.setBounds(114, 525, 186, 23);
    btnImg3.addActionListener(this);
    lblImg3.setIcon(img3b);
    lblImg3.setBounds(78, 314, 250, 200);
    add(lblImg3);
    add(btnImg3);

    btnImg4.setBounds(456, 525, 186, 23);
    btnImg4.addActionListener(this);
    lblImg4.setIcon(img4b);
    lblImg4.setBounds(421, 314, 250, 200);
    add(lblImg4);
    add(btnImg4);

    btnComecar.setBounds(68, 14, 89, 23);
    btnComecar.addActionListener(this);
    add(btnComecar);
    }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (e.getSource().equals(btnImg1)) {
        jogo.piscaImagen(img1, img1b, lblImg1);
    } else if (e.getSource().equals(btnComecar)) {
        jogo.comecaJogo();
        System.out.println(jogo.seqAlea);
        for (int i = 0; i < jogo.seqAlea.size(); i++) {
            switch (jogo.seqAlea.get(i)) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Posição: " + i + " " + jogo.seqAlea.get(i));
                jogo.piscaImagen(img1, img1b, lblImg1);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Posição: " + i + " " + jogo.seqAlea.get(i));
                jogo.piscaImagen(img2, img2b, lblImg2);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Posição: " + i + " " + jogo.seqAlea.get(i));
                jogo.piscaImagen(img3, img3b, lblImg3);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Posição: " + i + " " + jogo.seqAlea.get(i));
                jogo.piscaImagen(img4, img4b, lblImg4);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The logic of your `Timer` doesn't seem to make sense.  In fact, much of the logic you have in your buttons `ActionListener` should actually be in the `Timer`

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Remember, each `ActionListener` is executed on each trigger of the `Timer`, you are adding multiple `ActionListener`s to the `Timer`, but you're also not removing any

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but i just don't know how to handle the timer properly i guess. could you please enlight me about it, and how actionlistener in it works.

Comment: Can you give me more details about how it's suppose to be working?  Do you expect all four labels to change simultaneously or one at a time?

Comment: one at time, like a memory game :), actually thats the main problem, the images change simultaneously

Answer (score 1):

> one at time, like a memory game :)

There are multitudes of ways this might work, for example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton btnImg1 = new JButton();
    JButton btnImg2 = new JButton();
    JButton btnImg3 = new JButton();
    JButton btnImg4 = new JButton();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new Main();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public Main() {

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2)) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(200, 200);
            }
        };

        buttons.add(btnImg1);
        buttons.add(btnImg2);
        buttons.add(btnImg3);
        buttons.add(btnImg4);

        add(buttons);

        JButton play = new JButton("Play");
        add(play, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        play.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        List<JButton> sequence = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new JButton[]{btnImg1, btnImg2, btnImg3, btnImg4}));
        Collections.shuffle(sequence);
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

            private JButton last;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (last != null) {
                    last.setBackground(null);
                }
                if (!sequence.isEmpty()) {
                    JButton btn = sequence.remove(0);
                    btn.setBackground(Color.RED);
                    last = btn;
                } else {
                    ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                }
            }
        });
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

This just places all the buttons into a `List`, shuffles the list and then the `Timer` removes the first button from the `List` until all the buttons have been "flashed".

Now this is just using the button's `backgroundColor`, so you'd need to create a class which allows you to associate the `JButton` with "on" and "off" images, these would then be added to the `List` and the `Timer` executed in a similar manner as above

Comment: Thanks man, but I still don't get it: I need to create a random sequence to blink the buttons, and this sequence must be incremented if the user input is correct, so i guess the list must be outside the actionPerformed, right?

Comment: I mean, if I insert two more ImageIcon lists below the sequence list declaration, how should I compare them to choose which iten to set?

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do. `sequence` is the order in which the buttons should be changed.  If you need to add to, then yes, you will probably need it to be an instance field

Comment: Ok, but I would like to know why my code wont works, why it blink all images at once, when it should blink in the right order

Comment: @VictorIde Without running the code, I would say that ALL the `ActionListener`s are been triggered at the same time (sequentially) on each tick of the `Timer`, so they are racing through your list

Comment: Right, and could you please show me where should I stop it, or make it run sequentially but delaying between each call?

Comment: I did.  Use a single `ActionListener`